# cannot put my tornado process in the foreground after I log out then log in

Tags: nitrousio

I'm using nitrous.io box

I started a process using & to put it in the background, then logged out and logged in again.
I see it still running in the background:

`ps -aux |grep python
action     725  0.0  0.0  62912 13232 ?        S    21:40   0:00 python /home/action/workspace/web2py/gluon/contrib/websocket_messaging.py -k mykey -p 8888`

I want to put it in foreground, but I cant.

`(py27env)action@web2py-xxxx:~$ fg 725
-**bash: fg: 725: no such job**`

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try running python outside of VirtualEnv for moving processes between the foreground and the background.

Once python has started in the background, run `jobs` in the console to get the job id. From there you should be able to move the process to the foreground with `fg <number>`.

Answer (score 0):

I only use virtualenv because that is the only way to install tornado and doing this i´m forced to use python from my virtualenv otherwise tornado does not work

So, is there another solution?